# tcpdf doesn't priting HTML document with image properly - PHP

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

**My code to convert HMTL to PDF using tcpdf.**

```
$html =  '<pre>
          <br/>
          <h3><a href="/node/02" title="View Original Document">aa</a></h3>
          <br/>
          <img width="628" height="674" class="imagecache imagecache-assetimage" title="" alt="" src="http://test/a_image/AssignPage.jpg" />&nbsp</pre>';

    $htm = '<div style="font-size:40px !important;">'.$html.'</div>';
    $pdf->writeHTML($htm, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, '');
```

**Above code prints the following error message:**

```
TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get image: /path-of-the-image
```

*If HTML does not contains image it is working perfectly.*

What to do to resolve this issue ?

Any help will be thankful and grateful...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Try this in your address bar "http://test/a_image/AssignPage.jpg"" is it working ?

Comment: s. i checked it.. image is there !

Comment: try to print your html...may it will help you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Need to provide 777 permissions for cache folder located in tcfdf.**

And it works...

thanks...